# Is this possible to use three semicolons inside of for loop condition parenthesis?

Tags: c++, syntax

I was solving a C++ test question at [crossover.com](https://www.crossover.com) and there is a question which asks output of this:

```
for(unsigned char i=0;i&lt;128;i++)printf("hello world");
```

The [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) shows only one or two semicolons. I've never seen this kind of for loop before. Does it exist on C or newer **/** previous C++ versions?

There was **no** answer option with compilation error. Can I say that the question is wrong?

Comment: `&lt;` is a less-than sign escaped for a url. What you've shown doesn't compile. https://ideone.com/JXjlyH

Comment: `Can I say that the question is wrong?` absolutely! `&lt;` is `<` and is a typo. [fixed](https://ideone.com/Jx4AHx)

Comment: @RetiredNinja can you write that as an answer for me to mark correct?

Comment: Note that `&lt;` is _not_ another way to write `<` in **C/C++** code. It is a way to write `<` in **HTML**. That's why you won't see any mention of it in C/C++ references. All that happened here was an escaping error on the website you were reading. C and C++ do have some special [digraphs and trigraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C) which are ways of encoding some other characters like `{` and `}` on machines that don't have those characters, but these are very rarely used today.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelGeary! But I have a question, please help if I'm thinking wrong; how the compiler can understand that `&lt;` means `<`, rather than reading address of variable `lt`? In case, getting the address of variable `lt`: `std::cout << &lt;`

Comment: That's what I was explaining: the `&lt;` is not C/C++ syntax at all. It has no relation to these languages. If you paste that code into a C or C++ source file it will not compile. `&lt;` is **HTML** code that represents the `<` character. You shouldn't have seen this on the website at all; it was only displayed because of a bug in the website. When a website needs to display a `<` character, it is encoded in the HTML source as `&lt;` because `<` would have special meaning in HTML (it begins a tag).

Comment: Normally the browser would "unescape"`&lt;` and display it as `<`, but there are a few possible reasons why you might see `&lt;` in its raw form. For example, the code behind the website may have mistakenly run the text through an HTML encoder _twice_. The browser only unescapes it once, so you are left viewing the `&lt;` because of the website's mistake.

Comment: I understand that well from yours and @RetiredNinja's comments but Thanks for the detailed explanations for others Sir.

Comment: Glad to help. If you would like some more examples of what may have happened here, try doing a View Source on the very page we are looking at right now. (For a shortcut, use Ctrl+U on Windows/Linux, or Cmd+U on Mac.) Then do Ctrl+F or Cmd+F to search the page and enter `&lt;` into the search box. You will see that the `<` characters in the page have been encoded as `&lt;`, because `<` means something special in HTML. The browser changes this back to `<` for display. Now imagine what would happen if the server mistakenly did this escaping _twice_ instead of once. Oops!

Comment: Exactly Sir! The website uses some *script* for highlighting code blocks in boxes. And clearly the coder of the website made a mistake when using that *script*.

Comment: who down voted this question :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a mistake in the web page presenting the question. They meant to ask about :

```
for(unsigned char i=0;i<128;i++)printf("hello world")
```

but due to bad web design the `<` symbol was inadvertently replaced by `&lt;` . You should probably answer the question they meant to ask.

Answer (score 1):

There is an escaped section in the code. `&lt;` is actually `<`. So the question now becomes;

```
for(unsigned char i=0;i<128;i++)printf("hello world");
```

And it prints 128 times "hello world" next to each other like this;

hello worldhello world ... hello worldhello world

Comment: Yes but since the typo is not user-produced but rather some out-source related thus I put the answer

Comment: @Onur.A, Your answer doesn't answer neither the title of Question nor the any sentence in question with ends with question mark. Also  this is a test question, and leave the guessing output to the solver please. And also one can easily see that output by compiling.

Comment: @OrhanGaziHafif Welcome to SO! You have asked `I've never seen this kind of for loop before. Does it exist on C or newer / previous C++ versions?` and clearly my response includes answer to this as I've mentioned `There is an escaped section in the code. &lt; is actually <. So the question now becomes...` part.

Comment: Unfortunately, no bro, in C++, `&lt;` isn't actually `<`. It's accessing an address of a variable called `lt`. It's impossible for compiler to detect that it's `<` rather than accessing to the address of `lt` in this case: `std::cout << &lt;`. Compiler can't decide if it needs to throw missing semicolon exception or reading it as an **html** (why?) escape character. If you make your answer correct by editing it, ofc I could be happy to accept one of coder's answer from my country :)

Comment: @OrhanG.Hafif Let me rephrase my answer :) `&lt;` is not part of the actual code, it's an escaped section(error) caused by the website of crossover.com as they forgot to take action for it. The actual code is `for(unsigned char i=0;i<128;i++)printf("hello world");` So C++ compiler won't see any `&lt;` in the code as the actual code doesn't include it.

Comment: I've upvoted yours, but I've already accepted another clear one with the solution I did after comments of question. Actually The one was @RetiredNinja, who helped first but I think, he thought that the question is so easy. I don't know what's this thing is in #so actually. I've seen it before too. They don't want to answer easy questions :) I always think like, even it is easy, it's better for reading it as an answer, instead of comments.

Comment: @OrhanG.Hafif If it's a duplicate or could be solved with a little further information(inclusion of error log etc.), people generally choose to post it as a comment, it's up to the person indeed. Anyway, thanks for the upvote. The important point is you got the idea and good luck on the test!